# Racket: simplify arithmetic expressions with variables

Tags: racket, simplify, arithmetic-expressions

I am trying to implement a function

```
; (simplify expr)
;
; where expr is one of the following
; - a number
; - a symbol
; - a list of the form '(a operator b) where a and b are arithmetic expressions
```

The function is NOT supposed to simplify the arithmetic expression as far as possible, I just need it to simplify the subexpressions without variables:

examples:

```
(simplify '(3 + a))                  => '(3 + a)
(simplify '(((2 + (3 * 4)) * a) + 2) => '((14 * a) + 2)
(simplify '((2 + (3 - a)) * 2)       => '((2 + (3 - a)) * 2)
```

I already implemented a function that evaluates an arithmetic expression:

```
(define (eval t)
  (cond
    [(number? t) t]
    [else ((cond
            [(equal? (second t) '+) +]
            [(equal? (second t) '-) -]
            [(equal? (second t) '*) *]
            [(equal? (second t) '/) /])
           (eval (first t)) (eval (third t)))]))
```

This is what I have so far, but aside from the fact that it does not even work properly, I guess that there is a much better way.

```
(define (simplify t)
  (cond
    [(number? t) t]
    [(equal? 'a (first t)) `(,(first t) ,(second t) ,(simplify (third t))) ]
    [(equal? 'a (third t)) `(,(simplify (first t)) ,(second t) ,(third t)) ]
    [else ((cond
           [(equal? (second t) '+) +]
            [(equal? (second t) '-) -]
            [(equal? (second t) '*) *]
            [(equal? (second t) '/) /])
           (simplify (first t)) (simplify (third t)))]))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key insight is that

```
 (number operation number)
```

can be simplified to

```
the result of evaluating (number operation number)
```

So add a clause in simplify that checks for the pattern `(number operation number)` then use your `eval` function to find the result.

Comment: Thank you!
I wrote a function (match-pattern? t) (since I mustn't use the match function) that checks for the pattern (number operation number) in a list, but if it returns #true, it evaluates the whole list (what returns an error because of the variable), not just the (num op num) expressions. Can you give me a hint on that?

    (define (simplify t)
      (cond
        [(number? t) t]
        [(symbol? t) t]
        [(match-pattern? t) (eval t)]
        [else t]))

Comment: You need an extra clause that handles the case `(expression op expression)` and produces (simplified-expression op simplified-expression).